# Troublesome proof in Functional Analysis with dual vector space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Greetings to all of you

I have tried to prove the following theorem but I am having some troubles with it.
Let $X$ be a separable normed space and $(x_n')$ a bounded sequence in $X'$, then there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k}')$ and a functional $x' \in X'$ such that $\forall x \in X: x'_{n_k}(x) \rightarrow x'(x)$.

My idea was the following:

1.) $X$ is separable so $X=\overline{\{x_1,x_2,...\}}$ for some elements.

2.) Since this sequence is bounded we have $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: ||x_n'|| \le N$

3.)  Normalize the elements from 1 such that $\hat{x_i}:= \frac{x_i}{||x_i||}$( if this one is zero then keep it).

4.) Now I looked at the sequences ( I count each row as a sequence):
$$x_1'(\hat{x_1}) \quad x_2'(\hat{x_1}) \quad x_3'(\hat{x_1})\quad x_4'(\hat{x_1})...$$
$$x_1'(\hat{x_2}) \quad x_2'(\hat{x_2}) \quad x_3'(\hat{x_2})\quad x_4'(\hat{x_2})...$$
$$x_1'(\hat{x_3}) \quad x_2'(\hat{x_3}) \quad x_3'(\hat{x_3})\quad x_4'(\hat{x_3})...$$

Now every sequence is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore every sequence has a convergent subsequence, but I want to have a diagonal sequence so I only take the relevant elements in the first sequence let's say 
$$x_1'(\hat{x_1})  \quad x_3'(\hat{x_1})\quad x_4'(\hat{x_1})...$$

In that case 
$$x_1'(\hat{x_2}) \quad x_3'(\hat{x_2})\quad x_4'(\hat{x_2})...$$ is still bounded so take 
$$x_1'(\hat{x_2}) \quad x_4'(\hat{x_2})...$$
for example this one as a convergent subsequence(such a sequence exists by noticing that it is still bounded).
Now I proceed and what I finally take is a diagonal sequence $(x_{n_k}')$ that converges (by construction) for all $\hat{x_n}$.

My problem is that I want to construct $x'$ now as some sort of pointwise limit such that 
$\lim_k x_{n_k}'(x_j) = x'(x_j)$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. The problem is: This does not give me that $x' \in X'$. But how do I get that this one is continuous and linearly defined on $X$?

If I had that I could easily check that the limit exists for all $x \in X$ . Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: There should be a closure operator in 1. Also, the way it is written, both the sequence and the linear functional seem to come from $X'$, which makes no sense.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker you are right about the closure thing but why do you think is there a problem with the sequence and the linear functional?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Makes sense to me: the claim is that some subsequence converges to an element of $X'$. ->Lipschitz: is there anything wrong with using Banach-Alaoglu and the metrizability of the weak* topology on bounded sets?

Comment: yes, I have never heard of it ;-)

Comment: @PostNoBills You are right, I misread something.

Comment: OK, now you have heard of it: [sequential Banach-Alaoglu theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Sequential_Banach.E2.80.93Alaoglu_theorem) is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: this may be true but the problem is that these topology things seem to be far beyond what we are doing in our class, so I would rather appreciate it to stick to things that we know. do you think it is possible to stay with my proof?

Comment: An idea I had was to choose a largest possible linear independent set from these $x_1,x_2,...$ and to create a linear functional from this on a subspace and use Hahn-Banach. Unfortunately, it appears to me that it is impossible to use Banach Steinhaus since we are not dealing with Banach spaces

Comment: I suggest you follow the hint by Post No Bills. Banach-Alaoglu may seem like a big hammer but it's no big deal if you assume Tychonoff's theorem, which is covered in any analysis class. The usage of Tychonoff addresses, like knife through butter, _exactly_ where you are stuck...how do you show the "natural" limit functional is bounded? Separability then implies the metrizability of weak-* topology. So you're done.

Comment: okay, I will have a look at it. I will come back to you guys if I need help :-). thanks to all of you.